# Flow declaration files - getting started

Tags: flowtype

Suppose I have this in a file named "math.js".

```
function double(n) {
  return n * 2;
}

exports.double = double;
```

If I want to declare the parameter and return type of the "double" function in a separate file named "math.js.flow", what would I put in that file?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: I want to understand the syntax for keeping types in a separate file. Most of the time I will put the types directly in the file. I just want to see a working example of the other option.

Comment: @NatMote if you publish `.js.flow` files with your npm package, `flow` will typecheck usages of your package's exports.  That's the primary purpose of `.js.flow` files.

Answer (score 5):

You would put this in your `.js.flow` file:

```
// @flow

declare export function double(n: number): number;
```

Note that if your `.js` module contains `module.exports = function foo()` then you will need to do the following:

```
declare function foo(): void;
declare module.exports: typeof foo;
```

You can also generate `.js.flow` files with the `flow gen-flow-files` command.  At the time of writing, it's buggy and sometimes fails, so I still write my `.js.flow` files manually, but if it succeeds you can look at what it output to reverse engineer more aspects of the `.js.flow` format.

Comment: This has been the most frustrating part of Flow in my experience. You suggestion of `declare export function double(n: number): number;` is not working for me. I can have code that calls `double` with a string and Flow says `No Errors!`. When I use `flow gen-flow-files math.flow > math.flow.js` it generates a file that contains a comment that says `The file does not have an @flow at the top!`. Of course it doesn't. I'm trying to demonstrate how I can specify types for files that, for whatever reason, I cannot modify.

Comment: The bottom line for me is that I've yet to see an example of using a `.js.flow` that actually works, so as far as I can tell, that way of specifying types with Flow is broken. I would SO love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @MarkVolkmann well it can't typecheck modules that you can't add `// @flow` to.  But it can typecheck modules that use that if there's a `.js.flow` beside it.  If you put your code in a GitHub gist I'll take a look and see what's wrong.  I've been using `.js.flow` files for awhile without problems.

Comment: Thanks Andy! The gist is at https://gist.github.com/mvolkmann/fac4d915b02dcf3b7c6ea7b482f2fdcd

Comment: I should have just put `// @flow` in my code example, sorry about that.  Edited

Comment: @MarkVolkmann if this was helpful could you accept and upvote my answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.js.flow` files are treated just like source files. So for your example you could do something like this:

```
function double(n: number): number {
  return n * 2;
}

exports.double = double;
```

Again though, if I knew exactly what you are trying to achieve I might be able to give better advice. Usually you want to just properly annotate your source files.

Comment: I agree that usually it is best to annotate the source files. But suppose someone (not me) was opposed to requiring the use of software to strip the types before the code runs. They might prefer to specify the types in a separate files and leave the originals as pure JS. I just want to understand how that would work. Looking at your example, do I really have to specify the function implementations in the .js.flow file? I just want to specify the type signatures.

Comment: Sure, in that case you have a couple options. I believe you can put Flow types in comments (although I've never done it and I don't know where the docs are). That way you don't need to strip them before running it. I think in your `.js.flow` files you can also use something like `declare function double(n: number): number` to avoid including the entire implementation. I'm not 100% sure as I have not done either of these things, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to get ... use of "declare". I just can't get a simple, working example.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Fixed error in code and extra information

math.js.flow

```
// @flow

declare module.exports: {
    double: (n: number) => number;
}
```

math.js

```
function double(n) {
  return n * 2;
}

exports.double = double;
```

index.js

```
const double = require('./math').double;

console.log(double(20));
```

Here's an image so you can see the folder layout / flow working

[image: Simple working example]

To answer your comments about why `declare export function double(n: number): number;` doesn't work, see [this](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/#toc-declaring-an-es-module) and [this](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/#toc-declaring-a-commonjs-module)

In short, `declare export` is used for declaring a named export of a ES6 module, e.g `export const foo = 'bar'`. Your math module is a CommonJs module, so you have to use the `declare module.exports: ...` syntax